# Error when calling addFieldToFilter() to query model with where condition

Tags: magento-1.8, model, resource-model

I've created a Model and a Resource Model. I tried to query for records from the database through the `Mage::getModel()` function like this:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('custommodule/mymodel')->getCollection();
$model = $model->addFieldToFilter("model_id", 1);
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on boolean in C:\wamp\www\samplestore\testing.php on line 19
```

`model_id` is my primary key. I've no problem retrieving data when I do it this way:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('custommodule/mymodel');
$model = $model->load(1);
```

This is how my resource model look:

```
class TestNS_CustomModule_Model_Resource_MyModel extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/mymodel', 'model_id');
    }
}
```

And this is how my config.xml look:

```
<models>
    <custommodule>
        <class>TestNS_CustomModule_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>custommodule_resource</resourceModel>
    </custommodule>
    <custommodule_resource>
        <class>TestNS_CustomModule_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <mymodel>
                <table>testns_custommodule_moduletable</table>
            </mymodel>
        </entities>
    </custommodule_resource>
</models>
```

I can get the data if I do a `load(1)`, but not when I call . It seems like `getCollection()` is returning a `false` boolean, why is this so?

Why am I getting an error when calling `addFieldToFilter()`? If I can't do it this way, how can I add in a "where" clause to select a record from the model?

Comment: Can you show us resource model?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri Sure, I've just updated my question with my resource model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have missed a `Collection.php` file. You need this file in order to get or filter the collection.

```
class TestNS_CustomModule_Model_Resource_Mymodel_Collection
    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/mymodel');
    }
}
```

This will make sure your filter works. Good luck.

**UPDATE**

Your resource model should extend from here:

`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract`

So your `Mymodel.php` should be

```
class TestNS_CustomModule_Model_Resource_Mymodel extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custommodule/mymodel', 'model_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error after adding in a `Collection.php` in my Resource folder.

Comment: Check the naming, you cannot have `MyModel.php`, you should have `Mymodel.php` only. Same applies for all file and folder inside `CustomModule` (you can have `CustomModule`). And your extend is wrong.

Comment: My resource model and actual mode have the same file name as `MyModel.php`, but one is in the `resource` folder while the other is in the `Model` folder. Is this acceptable?

Comment: You should have `Mymodel.php` and `Resource/Mymodel/Collection.php`. Also can you show your etc/config.xml too?

Comment: @AdarshKahtr, I've added my config.xml to my question too.

Comment: Yeah, that looks ok, so I guess your file/folder naming is causing the harm. Check my updated answer and also comment.

Comment: yes, it turns out to be the folder issue! It works now!! Thank you so much!! :D

Answer (score 0):

xenon, Try changing in ur  resource model file

```
Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
```

to

```
Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
```

Comment: Thanks. I've actually tried this earlier, but I'm getting the same error. :(